# Add a CALayer sublayer centered over UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiimageview

- Xcode 7.2
- Swift 2

I am trying to overlay an Image with what I am calling a "BlurFilterMask". It is a CALayer that I dynamically add with Swift Code, here is the BlurFilterMask:

```
class BlurFilterMask : CALayer {

    private let GRADIENT_WIDTH : CGFloat = 50.0

    var origin : CGPoint = CGPointZero {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    var diameter : CGFloat = 50.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {
         CGContextSaveGState(ctx)

        let clearRegionRadius : CGFloat  = self.diameter * 0.5
        let blurRegionRadius : CGFloat  = clearRegionRadius + GRADIENT_WIDTH

        let baseColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        let colours : [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,     // Clear region
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6] // blur region color
        let colourLocations : [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0]
        let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (baseColorSpace, colours, colourLocations, 2)


        CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, gradient, self.origin, clearRegionRadius, self.origin, blurRegionRadius, .DrawsAfterEndLocation);

    }

}
```

In my `UIViewController.viewDidLoad()` I call addMaskOverlay() and here is the implementation:

```
 func addMaskOverlay(){
        let blurFilterMask = BlurFilterMask()

        blurFilterMask.diameter = 80 
        blurFilterMask.frame = heroImageView.bounds
        blurFilterMask.origin = heroImageView.center
        blurFilterMask.shouldRasterize = true

        heroImageView.layer.addSublayer(blurFilterMask)

        blurFilterMask.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
```

No matter what Simulator I run in, be it iPhone 5 or iPhone 6 or iPad 2, for examples, I always get the same center, width and height:

- print(heroImageView.center) = (300.0, 67.5)
- print(CGRectGetWidth(heroImageView.bounds)) = 600.0
- print(CGRectGetHeight(heroImageView.bounds)) //135.0

But the center of my BlurFilterMask is always somewhere different, depending on the device simulator and it never starts in the center of UIImageView, example in iPhone 5:

[image]

And here is iPhone 6:

[image]

I thought maybe I need vertically centering and horizontally centering constraints on my CALayer BlurFilterMask so I tried adding constraints:

```
heroImageView.layer.addSublayer(blurFilterMask)

let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: blurFilterMask, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: heroImageView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: blurFilterMask, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: heroImageView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

heroImageView.addConstraint(xConstraint)
heroImageView.addConstraint(yConstraint)
```

But I cannot add Constraints to a CALayer I do not think, I get an error when I try:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView, or NSLayoutGuide.'**

It seems like the issue might be constraints but if I cannot add constraints to a CALayer...

That code didn't help...

Not sure where to go from here, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try doing your measurements based on the device `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` ?

Comment: Are you saying use subtraction from the UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds and the my UIImageView.bounds to find the center of of the UIImageView?

Comment: Because if you saying just use the UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds that would center my BlurFilterMask over the entire View displayed and that is not what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `addMaskOverlay` call to `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` to see if the dimensions and center are the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that when `viewDidLoad` is called the layout has not been done yet so your measurements are being taken from the initial state of the view controller , most likely from the storyboard size if thats what you are using.

You need to call `blurFilterMask` once layout has completed and the final size of `heroImageView` is known.

You can do this by overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which is ...

> Called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews.

Read [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews) as there are some conditions but in your case this does work leaving you with this..

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var heroImageView: UIImageView!

    var blurFilterMask:BlurFilterMask! = nil

    func resetMaskOverlay(){

        if blurFilterMask == nil {

            blurFilterMask = BlurFilterMask()

            blurFilterMask.diameter = 120

            heroImageView.layer.addSublayer(blurFilterMask)

        }

        blurFilterMask.frame = heroImageView.bounds
        blurFilterMask.origin = heroImageView.center

    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        resetMaskOverlay()
    }

}
```

I assumed this line in `BlurFilterMask`

```
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, yDiff)*/
```

Was meant to be commented out as it didn't make much sense leaving...

```
class BlurFilterMask : CALayer {

    let GRADIENT_WIDTH : CGFloat = 50.0

     var origin : CGPoint = CGPointZero {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    var diameter : CGFloat = 50.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {
        CGContextSaveGState(ctx)

        let clearRegionRadius : CGFloat  = self.diameter * 0.5
        let blurRegionRadius : CGFloat  = clearRegionRadius + GRADIENT_WIDTH

        let baseColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        let colours : [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,     // Clear region
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6] // blur region color
        let colourLocations : [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0]
        let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (baseColorSpace, colours, colourLocations, 2)


        CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, gradient, self.origin, clearRegionRadius, self.origin, blurRegionRadius, .DrawsAfterEndLocation);

    }

 }
```

[image: test1-5s] [image: test1-6s+]

Comment: I got a feeling you are correct but I won't be able to check till late tomorrow, update you soon, thanks

Comment: Oops yes , my usual mistake. You need a once-only mech of some sort to stop that happening. See edit - I have added the layer as an ivar to track it.

Comment: Strange. that exact code is working for rotates on my sims , it's a bit flickery but nothing that couldn't be solved with some alpha. Alternatively leave the layer in place and reset its origin.

Comment: See new edit - rather than dumping the layer, i just reset it on layout changes. Cleaner IMO

Comment: Oh nice call on resetMaskOverlay(), very clean, I was wrong about blurFilterMask always being nil in willTransitionToTraitCollection, deleted my comment about that

Comment: hi, I am still having issues consistently centering a CALayer sublayer over a UIImage, check out my new question if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677678/consistenlty-centering-calayer-sublayer-over-a-uiimageview