# Consistenlty Centering CALayer Sublayer over a UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

- Xcode 7.2
- Swift 2

My issue is that I cannot consistently center my CALayer.

I have a related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400789/add-a-calayer-sublayer-centered-over-uiimageview). The answer to this question was forward progress and brings me to the issue I am having now. Note in the answer to my related question, @WarrenBurton seems to only test portrait mode.

I think this issue, which really is calculating/positioning a sublayer dead center over a UIImageView may relate to the actual size of the Image selected for the UIImageView but I could be wrong about this.

[image]

Here is my `print()` output for portrait mode rotation:

```
willTransitionToTraitCollection()!
blurFilerMask != nil
resetMaskOverlay()!
(160.0, 128.0)
328.0
200.0
BlurFilterMask -> drawInContext()!
```

But the CALayer is centered in Landscape mode:

[image]

Here is my `print()` output for landscape mode rotation:

```
willTransitionToTraitCollection()!
blurFilerMask != nil
resetMaskOverlay()!
(284.0, 108.0)
568.0
200.0
BlurFilterMask -> drawInContext()!
```

My UIImage Size Inspector Screenshot, Constraints most important part to consider perhaps:

[image]

My UIImage mode is `Scale To Fill`

Here is all the code in my `TestViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var heroImageView: UIImageView!
      var blurFilterMask:BlurFilterMask! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        resetMaskOverlay()
    }


    override func willTransitionToTraitCollection(newCollection: UITraitCollection, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.willTransitionToTraitCollection(newCollection, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
        print("willTransitionToTraitCollection()!")

        if blurFilterMask != nil {
            print("blurFilerMask != nil")
            blurFilterMask.removeFromSuperlayer()
            blurFilterMask = nil
        }

    }

    func resetMaskOverlay(){
        print("resetMaskOverlay()!")

        print(heroImageView.center)
        print(CGRectGetWidth(heroImageView.bounds))
        print(CGRectGetHeight(heroImageView.bounds))

        if blurFilterMask == nil {
            blurFilterMask = BlurFilterMask()
        }

        blurFilterMask.diameter = 80
        blurFilterMask.frame = heroImageView.bounds
        blurFilterMask.origin = heroImageView.center
        blurFilterMask.shouldRasterize = true
        heroImageView.layer.addSublayer(blurFilterMask)
        blurFilterMask.setNeedsDisplay()

    }

}
```

Here is my CALayer which I call `BlurFilterMask`:

```
import UIKit

class BlurFilterMask : CALayer {

    private let GRADIENT_WIDTH : CGFloat = 50.0

    var origin : CGPoint = CGPointZero {
        didSet {
            //setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    var diameter : CGFloat = 50.0 {
        didSet {
            //setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext) {
        print("BlurFilterMask -> drawInContext()!")
        CGContextSaveGState(ctx)

        let clearRegionRadius : CGFloat  = self.diameter * 0.5
        let blurRegionRadius : CGFloat  = clearRegionRadius + GRADIENT_WIDTH

        let baseColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        let colours : [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,     // Clear region
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.6] // blur region color
        let colourLocations : [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0]
        let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (baseColorSpace, colours, colourLocations, 2)


        CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, gradient, self.origin, clearRegionRadius, self.origin, blurRegionRadius, .DrawsAfterEndLocation);


    }

}
```

Now further testing of this issue, I can demonstrate the exact opposite of my first screenshots (the first scenario was: Portrait mode is NOT centered and Landscape mode is correctly centered).

In this next example. I have changed the UIImageView constraints so that fill the UIImageView fills the SuperView and you can see below my CALayer is correctly centered in Portrait mode but NOT Landscape mode, the exact opposite of my previous screenshot demo:

UIImageView Constraints:
[image]

Portrait mode with UIImageView "fill" superview constraints:

[image]

Landscape mode with UIImageView "fill" superview constraints:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your code is setting centre of your BlurFilterMask. Centre should centre of BlurFilterMask right? Use this updated 'resetMaskOverlay' function.

```
    func resetMaskOverlay(){
    print("resetMaskOverlay()!")

    print(heroImageView.center)
    print(CGRectGetWidth(heroImageView.bounds))
    print(CGRectGetHeight(heroImageView.bounds))

    if blurFilterMask == nil {
        blurFilterMask = BlurFilterMask()
    }

    blurFilterMask.diameter = 80
    blurFilterMask.frame = heroImageView.bounds
    blurFilterMask.origin = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(heroImageView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(heroImageView.bounds))
    blurFilterMask.shouldRasterize = true
    heroImageView.layer.addSublayer(blurFilterMask)
    blurFilterMask.setNeedsDisplay()

}
```

Comment: Just seeing this answer, will try when I get home tonight